# I need the name of a Hitachi TX26D60VC1CAB panels connector (picture included)

Tags: connector, display, panel

i have recently ventured into reverse-engineering this Compaq 420cxs panel. I have managed to find a semi-complete datasheet (more of a pinout-diagram) for it and with the help of an esp8266 based dev board, i made it display some colors.

But i would much rather drive it using a FPGA with the correct connector. 
The only problem now is that i just cant seem to find the name of this weird connector, maybe someone on here can help me.
[image: The Connector]
The connector has 31pins (yes 31, 16 on one and 15 on the other side) and a pitch of 1mm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's one of [these](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/DF9-31P-1V(69)/DF9-31P-1V(69)CT-ND/4576428), Hirose Electric Co Ltd DF9-31P-1V(69). The mating connector would probably be [this one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/DF9-31S-1V(69)/H121943CT-ND/3830810), Hirose Electric Co Ltd DF9-31S-1V(69).

Comment: Yes! That looks like its just what i was searching for. Thank you!

Comment: Digikey, Mouser, Newark, and similar distributors are very good for finding things like this. They let you search by features like pin pitch and number of contacts. Give it a try, next time you need something like this!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a 1mm pitch mezzanine type connector for board-to-board connections.

Without more measurements of the connector dimensions it is hard to give an exact part number. However you can use distributer websites search tools to try and find similar connectors.

The [following DigiKey Search](https://www.digikey.co.uk/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-board-to-board-connectors-arrays-edge-type-mezzanine/308?FV=1600062%2C164006c%2C1680002%2C1f140000%2Cffe00134%2C1c0002%2C1c0006&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=100) reveals 34 connectors in stock that seem to match your description (i.e. 31 pins, 1mm pitch, mezzanine connector). Several of those appear from a cursory glance to be a similar series of connector.

Hirose part [DF9-31S-1V](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/DF9-31S-1V(69)/H121943CT-ND/3830810), or Harwin part [M40-6203146](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/harwin-inc/M40-6203146/952-3059-ND/3922252) appear to be promising.